# How can I make all values in class appear when nothing is chosen from the drop down menu?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Please help. I cant seem to make all files appear at the same time. And I think it's because of the year option in my codes. It's like the year option must have at least one year chosen for it to work. I need to know how can i make a default option which will display all results of the years. e.g.  results 2007 - 2013.

Search.php codes

```
<?php
$rpdsad=$_POST['rpdsad'];
$type=$_POST['project'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$section=$_POST['section'];
$adviser=$_POST['adviser'];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('saddb');

if($rpdsad=="sad"){
/*1 query search*/
    if (empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><tr class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE section='$section' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE year='$year' and section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE section='$section' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*4 query search*/
    elseif(!empty($adviser) && !empty($type) && !empty($section) && !empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from sadt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>SAD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['sadcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
}

/*rpd*/
elseif ($rpdsad=="rpd"){
/*1 query search*/
    if (empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/
/*1 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><tr class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE section='$section' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE year='$year' and section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year) && empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*2 query search*/
    elseif(empty($section) && empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($type)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE section='$section' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($section)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*3 query search*/
    elseif(empty($adviser)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and year='$year'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }
/*end of section*/

/*4 query search*/
    elseif(!empty($adviser) && !empty($type) && !empty($section) && !empty($year)){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from rpdt WHERE type='$type' and section='$section' and year='$year' and adviser='$adviser'");
        echo "<div align=center><table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 class=\"tabs\"><TR class=\"sabt\"><td>RPD Code</td><td>Year</td><td>Section</td><td>Title</td><td>Type of OLS</td><td>Adviser</td><td>Group Leader</td></tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<tr class=\"sbat\" valign=top><td nowrap>".$row['rpdcode']."</td><td>".$row['year']."</td><td>".$row['section']."</td><td style=\"text-align: left\">".$row['title']."</td><td>".$row['type']."</td><td>".$row['adviser']."</td><td>".$row['groups']."</td><td>";
        }
        echo "</table></div><BR>";
    }

/*end of section*/
}
?>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: do you have any Javascript? and also post your PHP script.

Comment: Sorry but i'm still new to this that's why i'm still not familiar. I'm working on my first php program.

Comment: you should read this before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Will `<select class=year size=8>` do what you want?

Comment: @jolomercado please post all the code you have for your program and describe exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @stackErr I need to know what value will I put in "<option class="year" value="">Select Year</option>" so that the results from year 2007 up to 2013 will appear if no year is chosen. Thank you.

Comment: We cant help you unless you provide your php script

Comment: @stackErr I've posted the entire codes sir.

Comment: @jolomercado there is an extra space `$(".resultcontainer") .load(` right before load, change it to `$(".resultcontainer").load(`

Comment: @StackErr Still works the same sir. What I meant is, If I choose the SAD or RPD option and click search without choosing any from the other dropdowns, the whole database for each option will appear. Because when I do it, there is nothing showing up.

Comment: @jolomercado this should be done in your PHP script. Post your php script. The contents of `search.php`

Comment: @stackErr There sir. I posted the codes of my search.php. Thank you very much for helping me sir.

Comment: @jolomercado your php logic is very convoluted, you should simplify it. Currently you are missing too many cases for your php script to run properly. Read here for proper if-elseif-else syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php. You are missing the else statements.

Comment: @stackErr Sorry sir. It's my first time to make a php program. Can you suggest an if else code that'll make the databases appear when RPD or SAD is selected?

Comment: @jolomercado are any of the dropdowns mandatory?

Comment: @stackErr The SAD or RPD dropdown menu is the only mandatory element. The others are only optional if the user wants the search to be as few as possible. The other choices must be in dropdown form.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the general code that you will need, you will need to add the echo statements and the queries.

```
<?php
$rpdsad=$_POST['rpdsad'];
$type=$_POST['project'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$section=$_POST['section'];
$adviser=$_POST['adviser'];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('saddb');


/*
cases for "sad"
all empty
year
type
section
adviser
type year
type section
type adviser
year section
year adviser
section adviser
type year section
type year adviser
type adviser section
year adviser section
year section adviser type
*/

/* 
cases for "rpd"

all empty
year
section
year section

*/
if($rpdsad=="sad"){
    if(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //all empty
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //type
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && !empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //type and year
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && empty($year) && !empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //type and section
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //type and adviser
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && !empty($year) && !empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //type, year and section
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && !empty($year) && empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //type, year and adviser
    }
    elseif(!empty($type) && empty($year) && !empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //type, adviser and section
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && !empty($year) && empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //year
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && !empty($year) && !empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //year and section
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && !empty($year) && empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //year and adviser
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && !empty($year) && !empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //year, adviser and section
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && !empty($section) && empty($adviser))
    {
        //section
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && !empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //section and adviser
    }
    elseif(empty($type) && empty($year) && empty($section) && !empty($adviser))
    {
        //adviser
    }
    else{
        //all fields 
    }
}
else{   //RPD
    if(empty($year) && empty($section))
    {
        //all empty
    }
    elseif(!empty($year) && empty($section))
    {
        //year
    }
    elseif(empty($year) && !empty($section))
    {
        //section
    }
    else{
        //all fields 
    }
}
?>
```

there is definitely a better way of doing this...I will update the solution if I think of it.

You also have quiet a few syntax errors in your HTML, use an IDE or validate your HTML here: [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)